# Flutter Exception : type '() => Future<Database>' is not a subtype of type 'Database'

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm trying to save data into offline database ([sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)).
but getting an exception `type '() => Future<Database>' is not a subtype of type 'Database'`  with`init()` method return type ,
and I'm able to understand but unable to handle it.

**CODE:**

```
class DatabaseClient {
 static DatabaseClient _singleton = new DatabaseClient._internal();

 factory DatabaseClient() {
   return _singleton;
 }

 DatabaseClient._internal();
 Database _db;

 Future<Database> init() async {
   Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   String dbPath = join(path.path, OFFLINE_DB_FILENAME);

   _db = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1, onCreate: _create);
   return _db;

 }


Future _create(Database db, int version) async {

 await db.execute("""
   CREATE TABLE masterdata (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     parentKey TEXT,
     key TEXT NOT NULL,
     jsonData TEXT NOT NULL,
     masterDataName TEXT NOT NULL,
     createdDate TEXT NOT NULL
   )""");

 await db.execute("""
   CREATE TABLE syncqueue (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     key TEXT NOT NULL,
     value TEXT NOT NULL,
     jsonPostData TEXT NOT NULL,
     event TEXT NOT NULL,
     error TEXT,
     createdDate TEXT NOT NULL,
     syncFlag INTEGER NOT NULL default 0
   )""");

}
```

Comment: your DatabaseClient class looks fine. I think your error might where you are calling `init()`

Comment: Yep, problem with return type of `init()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The **_db** is an object of **Database** not **Future** in your **init** method

Try...

```
Future<Database> init() async {
   Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   String dbPath = join(path.path, OFFLINE_DB_FILENAME);

   return openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1, onCreate: _create);
 }
```